# there is some way to change the text of the days in a calendar?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

By default, in the days of calendar it is shown the day of the month, but I would like to modify the calendar to be able to show more text, like the events of the day.

I have serach on internet and I have found examples how to create a new control, but I would like to know if it is a way to modify the estandar control to show this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the Data displayed in a Datepicker- or Calendarcontrol you need to modify its control template.

This is the way to go if you want to extend any WPF Control.
You can find information on how to specifity modify the calendar control [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/dd882520.aspx).